# Failed to run scripts in multiple remote host by ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

I write a deployAll.sh, which read ip_host.list line by line, then add group for all the remote hosts,

when I run: sh deployAll.sh

results:

```
Group is added to 172.25.30.11
```

not expected results:

```
Group is added to 172.25.30.11
Group is added to 172.25.30.12  
Group is added to 172.25.30.13
```

Why it just execute the first one? please help, thanks a lot!

**deployAll.sh**

```
    #!/bin/bash

    function deployAll()
    {
        while read line;do
            IFS=';' read -ra ipandhost<<< "$line"
            ssh "${ipandhost[0]}" "groupadd -g 1011 test"
            printf "Group is added to ${ipandhost[0]}\n"
        done < ip_host.list
    }

deployAll
```

**ip_host.list**

```
172.25.30.11;test-30-11
172.25.30.12;test-30-12
172.25.30.13;test-30-13
```

Comment: Strange, it works for me. Post the result of `echo $BASH_VERSION` and when you run the script with `bash -x deployAll.sh`.

Comment: You really want to check out the Ansible project: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/quickstart.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a frequent problem which is caused by the special behavior of `ssh`, which sucks up *stdin*, starving the loop ( i.e. `while read line;do ...;done` )

Please see [Bash FAQ 89](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089) which discusses this subject in detail.

I also just answered ( and solved ) a similar question regarding `ffmpeg` with the same behavior as `ssh` in this case. Here: [When reading a file line by line, I only get to execute ffmpeg on the first line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36584391/when-reading-a-file-line-by-line-i-only-get-to-execute-ffmpeg-on-the-first-line/36584584#36584584).

## TL;DR :

There are three main options:

- Using `ssh`'s `-n` option. Quoted from `man ssh`:

> ```
>   -n     Redirects  stdin  from  /dev/null  (actually,  prevents reading from stdin).  This must be used when ssh is run in the background.  A common trick is to use this to run X11 programs on a remote
>           machine.  For example, ssh -n shadows.cs.hut.fi emacs & will start an emacs on shadows.cs.hut.fi, and the X11 connection will be automatically forwarded over an encrypted channel.  The ssh pro‐
>           gram will be put in the background.  (This does not work if ssh needs to ask for a password or passphrase; see also the -f option.)
> ```

- Adding a `</dev/null` at the end of `ssh`'s line ( i.e. `ssh ... </dev/null` ) will fix the issue and will make `ssh` behave as expected.
- Let `read` read from a [File Descriptor](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/FileDescriptor) which is unlikely to be used by a random program:

  ```
     while IFS= read -r line <&3; do
         # Here read is reading from FD 3, to which 'ip_host.list' is redirected.
     done 3<ip_host.list
  ```

Comment: Hi Rany, Thanks a lot, it works for me! I added "</dev/null" at the end of ssh's line, now everything is OK!

Answer (score 1):

Without the `ssh` command (which wouldn't make sense on my network), I get the expected output so I suspect that the `ssh` command is swallowing the remaining standard input. You should use the `-n` flag to prevent `ssh` from reading from `stdin` (equivalent to redirecting `stdin` from `/dev/null`):

```
ssh -n "${ipandhost[0]}" "groupadd -g 1011 test"
```

or

```
ssh "${ipandhost[0]}" "groupadd -g 1011 test" < /dev/null
```

See also [How to keep script from swallowing all of stdin?](https://serverfault.com/questions/606922/how-to-keep-script-from-swallowing-all-of-stdin)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to generate ssh keys through ssh-keygen command and replace existing public key file (if any). After which installation will resume.