# When reading a file line by line, I only get to execute ffmpeg on the first line

Tags: bash, video, ffmpeg

I'm writing a Bash script in which I read a file line by line ( well, `<(find /home/user/ -iname "*.MP4")` to be exact ) , and for each line I execute `ffmpeg`, so I'm doing something like this:

```
while read -r line; do
    ffmpeg -i "$line" [ MORE OPTIONS ... ]
done < <(find /home/user/ -iname "*.MP4")
```

Though, for some reason, **only the first line** is being processed successfuly.

Any idea why my code ignores all other lines ?

Comment: Try adding another line inside the loop above the `ffmpeg` line... `echo Processing $line`. Or try changing your shebang line to `#!/bin/bash -xv`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a frequent problem which is caused by the special behavior of `ffmpeg` (also happens with `ssh` ).

Quoted from [Bash FAQ 89](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089) which handles your case **almost exactly**:

> What's happening here? Let's take the first example. read reads a line from standard input (FD 0), puts it in the file parameter, and then ffmpeg is executed. ***Like any program you execute from BASH, ffmpeg inherits standard input***, which for some reason it reads. I don't know why. But in any case, when ffmpeg reads stdin, ***it sucks up all the input from the find command, starving the loop***.

## TL;DR :

There are two main options:

- Adding a `</dev/null` at the end of `ffmpeg`'s line ( i.e. `ffmpeg -i "$line" [ MORE OPTIONS ] ... </dev/null` ) will fix the issue and will make `ffmpeg` behave as expected.
- Let `read` read from a [File Descriptor](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/FileDescriptor) which is unlikely to be used by a random program:

  ```
     while IFS= read -r line <&3; do
         # Here read is reading from FD 3, to which 'file' is redirected.
     done 3<file
  ```