# Why is this while loop not looping?

Tags: bash, loops

I have the following bash script `deploy.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Some useful resources:
# while read ip user pass; do : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92664/how-to-deploy-programs-on-multiple-machines
# -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no: http://askubuntu.com/questions/180860/regarding-host-key-verification-failed
# -T: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/how-to-fix-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error
# echo $pass |: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955298/use-sudo-with-password-as-parameter

while read ip user pass; do 
  echo $ip
  sshpass -p "$pass" ssh $user@$ip  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -T "
  echo 'yo'
  "
  echo 'done'
done < servers.txt
```

`servers.txt` contains:

```
53.12.45.74 my_username my_password
54.12.45.74 my_username my_password
57.12.45.74 my_username my_password
‌‌
```

From my understanding, the `while read ip user pass; do […] done < servers.txt` should loop over all three lines of `servers.txt`.

However, when I try to run it, it only performs one iteration:

```
ubuntu@server:~$ bash deploy.sh
53.12.45.74
yo
done
ubuntu@server:~$
```

Why?

---

If the loop is simply:

```
while read ip user pass; do 
      echo $ip
done < servers.txt
```

it does perform all three iterations:

```
ubuntu@server:~$ bash deploy.sh
53.12.45.74
54.12.45.74
57.12.45.74
ubuntu@server:~$
```

Comment: Is that a complete script or a representative of the real script? If it's a representative, you may have overlooked a `break` statement inside the while loop.

Comment: @alvits  complete script, I just changed the IPs, usernames and passwords.

Comment: It would seem `sshpass` is taking control of `stdin` or possibly replacing it and causing `while` loop to lose input from redirected `stdin`. Try to run `sshpass` within a subshell like `(sshpass -p "$pass" ssh $user@$ip  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -T "
  echo $pass | sudo -S sudo /etc/init.d/ganglia-monitor restart
  ")` and see if the problem gets resolved.

Comment: @alvits: I think that's right.   Consider posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sshpass` is taking control of `stdin` or possibly replacing it and causing `while` loop to lose input from redirected `stdin`.

To work around this issue, avoid reading from stdin.

First, load the file into an array using a `while` loop.

```
while read line; do
    entries+=("$line")
done < servers.txt
```

Next, use `for` loop to parse the lines and execute `sshpass` within this loop.

```
for line in "${entries[@]}"; do
  set $line
  ip=$1
  user=$2
  pass=$3
  echo $ip
  sshpass -p "$pass" ssh $user@$ip  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -T "
  echo 'yo'
  "
  echo 'done'
done
```

The second loop doesn't read from `stdin`.

But I will recommend [Rany Albeg Wein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5649859/rany-albeg-wein) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36584819/5649859) using a separate descriptor than the current `stdin`.

```
while read ip user pass <&3; do 
  echo $ip
  sshpass -p "$pass" ssh $user@$ip  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -T "
  echo 'yo'
  "
  echo 'done'
done 3<servers.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, I have just tried it, the issue still persists: it only performs one iteration :(

Comment: @FrankDernoncourt I answered a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/36584819/5649859

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein Thanks for the link, sorry I missed it when Googling around.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Some useful resources:
# while read ip user pass; do : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92664/how-to-deploy-programs-on-multiple-machines
# -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no: http://askubuntu.com/questions/180860/regarding-host-key-verification-failed
# -T: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/how-to-fix-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error
# echo $pass |: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955298/use-sudo-with-password-as-parameter

while read ip user pass; do

  if [ -n "$ip" ]; then

    echo "IP[$ip] USER[$user] PASS[$pass]";

    # dont forget to uncomment this two lines here:
    #sshpass -p "$pass" ssh $user@$ip  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -T "
    #echo 'yo'

    echo ""; # Just a blank line"
    echo "done.";

  else
    echo "Empty value.";
  fi

done < servers.txt
```

So, now it works.

Comment: Thanks, I have just tried it, the issue still persists: it only performs one iteration :(